# How to implement a file download with Node.js's fs module and express

Tags: node.js, download, express

Because the file should be generated dynamically, maybe I should use the fs modules's writeStream. But I couldn't find any example codes with my poor googling. Sorry.

More specifically, I want to give a CSV file or a PDF file with my datas in the MongoDB, when someone requests.

Anyone, please give me some hints.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), I can implement like this.

```
app.get('/down2', function(req, res){
  var filename = 'data.csv';
  res.attachment(filename);
  res.end('hello,world\nkeesun,hi', 'UTF-8'); //Actually, the data will be loaded form db.
});
```

How simple is it. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think it's a good idea to save file to the disc and then send it using `res.attachment` if you received data for you csv from db link and it doesn't exist on the disk in the first place. You already have the data, why not just set headers and then `res.send(generatedCSVcontent)`?

Comment: I didn't save data to some file. I just send the data as you said. The Above filename is just file name that is used to request header. Actually, res.attachment() is very similar with the first answer. It just set the header with the filename and Content-type.

Comment: @Whiteship `res.end` should not be there for larger files other wise it will always download file with 0 byte

Answer (score 2):

you don't need fs, just stream your data from db in request handler

you can set file metadata using [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=genome.jpeg; 
  modification-date="Wed, 12 Feb 1997 16:29:51 -0500";
Content-Description: a complete map of the human genome
```